# Can't connect to cloud mysql from app engine php standard environment with laravel app and unix socket

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, eloquent, google-cloud-sql

I spent last 2 days on this issue doing research and troubleshooting, but could not find a way to fix this.

I am trying to connect to Google Cloud Sql instance (2nd gen mysql) from App Engine Standard Environment using Laravel Framework.

My app.yaml looks like this

```
runtime: php73

runtime_config:
  document_root: public

handlers:
  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: public/favicon.ico
    upload: public/favicon\.ico

env_variables:
  DB_DATABASE: DB_NAME
  DB_USERNAME: USER_NAME
  DB_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
  DB_SOCKET: "/cloudsql/SOCKET_NAME"
```

I am getting 500 error (Error Reporting is empty)
In Logger I get this

```
2020/03/22 22:40:08 [error] 20#20: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1255
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1221): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection(NULL)
#1 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1051): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
#2 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(968): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
#3 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1004): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newModelQuery()
#4 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(957): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
#5 /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1620): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQuery()
#6 /srv...PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in /srv/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1255
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an answer: [CONNECTING FROM APP ENGINE (FLEX AND STANDARD) TO CLOUD SQL USING TCP AND UNIX DOMAIN SOCKETS 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328359/how-to-connect-to-cloud-sql-mysql-database-from-app-engine)

Remember that:

> At this time App Engine standard enviroments do not support connecting
> to the Cloud SQL instance using TCP. Your code should not try to
> access the instance using an IP address (such as 127.0.0.1 or
> 172.17.0.1) unless you have configured Serverless VPC Access.So let's configure Serverless VPC Access.

## EDIT

your env variable in app.yaml

```
env_variables:
  # Replace USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, and CONNECTION_NAME with the
  # values obtained when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  CLOUDSQL_USER: "test"
  CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: "root"
  CLOUDSQL_DSN: "mysql:dbname=data;unix_socket=/cloudsql/your-project:us-central1:your-instance"
```

and you connection code:

```
$dsn = getenv('CLOUDSQL_DSN');
$user = getenv('CLOUDSQL_USER');
$password = getenv('CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD');
// create the PDO client
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

This was working for me. You can find a detailed example here:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples.git
    cd php-docs-samples/appengine/php72/cloudsql
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I came up to your post during research, unfortunately this is more of a Laravel + App Engine issue.

As I wrote, I am trying to connect using unix socket, which I specified in my env as /cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME